# Failed to use volumes

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I am trying to use volumes.

I created an app that reads from and writes to a file.

Either if I run it like that (without a volume):

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 hello-express
```

or if I run it like that (with a volume):

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 -v myvol:/myvol hello-express
```

I get the same result: the data is persisted after I stop and start the contianer, but it's deleted after I remove the container and run it again.

So something is wrong here.

Comment: After your second command check if your volumes exists by "docker volume ls" and do the same after deleting the container. 

did you try creating a volume in Dockerfile and attaching it while writing the command?

Comment: @MuhammadFarrukhFaizy you are correct. I forgot to create a volume. Now I have created it and it's working.

Comment: @MuhammadFarrukhFaizy I got to the answer thanks to your help so you can post an aswer and I will accept it.

Comment: done. I have posted my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create the Volume in DockerFile and attach it while running the command with the container you want. As volume are isolated with container and they have no dependency to the specific container.
You can refer to this good [article](https://container42.com/2014/11/03/docker-indepth-volumes/) of volumes as well. Hope it helps.